# VBA code to create button that leads to hidden worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a module that creates a new hidden worksheet with a specific name with the click of a button. The specific name is also added on a list in the initial worksheet. I would like the module to automatically create a new button in the initial worksheet, that when clicked, opens the hidden worksheet that was initially created. I am a novice in this area, so I do apologize if this question is not up to Stack Overflow's standard.
The current code I have is:

```
Set ws = Sheets("INPUT")

financing = ws.Range("E2").Value
compName = ws.Range("E3").Value

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Cells(lastRow, 1) = financing
ws.Cells(lastRow, 2) = compName

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = compName & "-" & financing
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Visible = xlSheetHidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally better to store a reference to your new worksheet within a variable.  You don't need to rely on the position or the name of the worksheet then - both of which can be changed by the user.

This code gives the button the same name as the worksheet it's meant to be pointing to *(I'm hoping that won't cause any problems with naming conventions)*.
The code that runs when you press the button looks at the button name and activates that sheet.

```
Sub AddButton()

    Dim btn As Button
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With wrkSht
        .Name = "compNameValue - FinancingValue"
        .Move After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End With

    Set btn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Buttons.Add(20, 20, 20, 20)
    With btn
        .ShapeRange.IncrementTop 100
        .ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 100
        .OnAction = "MacroTest"
        .Name = wrkSht.Name
    End With

End Sub

Sub MacroTest()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Application.Caller)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

You may want to update `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` depending on your needs.
`ThisWorkbook` is always the book containing the code that's running.
`ActiveWorkbook` is, as it says, the workbook that's currently active.

Comment: Thanks Darren, highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi again Darren,
This code worked well, but as you mentioned, it is probably better using a reference or a hyperlink to the "hidden" worksheet in the new cell that was created on the initial worksheet. Do you have any tips how to create a hyperlink to the new "hidden" worksheet in the cell that was created on the initial worksheet ("INPUT")?

Comment: Nvm Darren, figured it out!

Comment: Good stuff.  I was thinking about hyperlinks after your comment but you'd need to catch the `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` event so it can unhide the sheet first - not sure what problems you'd run into as haven't had time to look into it too far.

Comment: Exactly. I decided to keep the worksheets visible, as the only negative effects would be the aesthetics of the workbook. I am now trying to code the process of duplicating another worksheet when using my command button, instead of creating a blank worksheet (just posted another thread). As I mentioned, quite new to this, but extremely fascinating!

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Create a button

You can create a button using the development-tab in excel. There is a button called "insert" and then you insert a "Active-X Button" note there are also commandbuttons but they are for the compatibility with older versions. Do not use them. By clicking on the Design Mode Button in the development-tab in Excel you enter the design mode.

## 2 Enter the Code in the CommandButton_Click() module

When you are in the design mode double click on the button and it will show you something like this:

```
Private Sub BUTTONNAME_click()
' Enter Code here OR even better call code from module
Sub End
```

You can then do ahead and enter the code OR even better call the code from a modul. Button code will then look like this:

```
Private Sub BUTTONNAME_click()
call modulename.subname()
Sub End
```

And the module code will look like this:

```
Sub Subname() 
Set ws = Sheets("INPUT")

financing = ws.Range("E2").Value
compName = ws.Range("E3").Value

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Cells(lastRow, 1) = financing
ws.Cells(lastRow, 2) = compName

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = compName & "-" & financing
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Note here: As I understood your problem you do not know how to run code with a button.  I assume your code works.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your answer. I have already been able to link the module to the button. The question was regarding adding another button automatically within the code, to easily get access to the hidden worksheet initially created. May not have explained it that well. I am looking at the option to store a reference instead of creating a new button for every "case".